# Difference between ISAPI rule and Method UriTemplate

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, url-rewriting, isapi

I'm trying to understand basic concepts of using .NET URL Rewrite.

I have a WCF REST Service which exposes several methods.

When invoking a method, I can define a URITemplate for it

E.g

```
[OperationContract, WebGet(UriTemplate = "/A/B?start={start}&finish={finish}&destinations={destinations}&resolution={resolution}")]
```

How is that different from defining ISAPI rule?

Answers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So after getting no responses nor answers, I decided to post my own answer, which I think is good enough.

Both options allows rewriting the URL.

The ISAPI (.NET URL Rewrite) allows doing it in the **IIS level**, while the Method attribute is in the **application level**.

This means that:

1. Changing the Rewrite rule for the method attribute will need to be followed by a compilation, as this is a code change, while changing the IIS rule will need to be followed by a recycle of the application pool.
2. In addition, while in the IIS level, the rule can be defined for multiple applications, which cannot be done using the method attribute.